# Hidden features of PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I know [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is young IDE but id like to know if you guys have found some candy while using it. I know from experience that JetBrains IDE's are filled with candy and can't wait to find it all.

Please list your tips, perhaps something you did not first expected to be there.

Comment: Here is one: `ALT+SHIFT+S`, search for memory: `IDE Settings>Appearance` -> tick `Show memory indicator`. A memory bar will be shown at the bottom right corner. Click this bar to run a garbage collection / memory sweep.

Comment: @LorenzLoSauer This is now under Preferences>Appearance & Behavior>Appearance. Still `Show memory indicator`, though. :) At least it is in the Community Edition. YMMV.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

As the lead developer of `PyCharm`, I can tell you that we don't usually hide features in random places, and there are a few reliable ways to discover most of them.

- Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking on everything (methods, functions, template tag names and parameters, etc.)
- If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking works, usually so does completion (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>), rename (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>) and Find Usages (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>)
- Look through the menus and try out the actions that seem interesting
- Look at Settings | Inspections to configure the warnings which can be highlighted by `PyCharm`, and note that many of the inspections have quickfixes to correct the problems automatically
- Read the [blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and try out the features highlighted there.

Comment: I didn't want to impose that you did hide features. I'd like to find out what people find most usefull and what not so obvious. PS. Blogs are not the best way to advertise neat features to users, "Tip of the day" is. You should ship new tips with every build.

Comment: in fact there're always features that are relatively hard to access. IDEA has thousands of those. JetBrains doesn't hire designers for the Views, do they? ;)

Comment: CMD + Shift + A and type in what you want to do! 60% of the time, it works every time. :)

Answer (score 33):

I have recently discovered an option (I think it's off by default):

> Surround selection on typing quote or brace

Basically if you can quickly make a string from anything, just press Ctrl-W to select and then type quote. Awesome :)

PS: To enable this use settings search function, search for: `surround`

Comment: On how to enable this option, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27168576/1316649

Comment: It's easier to just use search option in settings, serach for: Surround.

Comment: IMHO this should be on by default but it is not and it has taken me ages to find this. Thanks

Comment: Can confirm - (surprisingly) not on by default, glad I found this thread, missed that from eclipse.

Comment: I know this is old but is there any shortcut to remove the quotes or braces? It would make my day.

Answer (score 26):

I like ctrl-w, the select block function. I've never ran across this before I think it's great to be able to select a function/if block by just pressing ctrl-w a couple of times.

Comment: I would count this as ugly-secret considering that Ctrl+W became the defacto-standard for close-tab/window (cross-platform).

Comment: It's silly that they used Ctrl+W as a default, but you can override any shortcut though.

Comment: `Option-Up`/`Option-Down` on OS X.

Answer (score 11):

This isn't PyCharm specific, I actually discovered it in IntelliJ but I though the PyCharm users should benefit too...

Try Alt+Click (Ctrl+Alt+Click if using Gnome default keymap) and drag to select text. It will select bounded blocks instead of complete lines using word wrap. These selected blocks can be used to type repetitive text or delete many parts of a line at once. Try it, you will find uses for it more often than you think!

Comment: Sadly you can only do that with boxes. Sublime Text 2/3 allow you to select arbitrarily any piece of text. And write at different places at once. That also works together with the search. Lets hope we see something like that in this lovely IDE too.

Comment: I just tried it in PyCharm 4.5.3 on a Mac. I was able to Option-click in different places and create multiple carets. I could then type text and it appeared in all of these places.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is a **hidden** feature really but when you know about it makes testing so much easier.

If you run your tests through PyCharm you can click on the names and lines of the backtrace to take you to the exact line in your python code. Makes testing so much easier.

Answer (score 5):

Control-clicking a view method in a URLconf will open views.py and bring you right to that method. Similarly, control-clicking template names in a view, and in other templates (like in the `extends` tag) will bring you to that template.

Not hidden, but when editing a CSS file, it shows the colors in the gutter for any styles that use color. I love that. Also for CSS: code insight offers optimizations of tags, as well as graying out unused tags.

When editing an HTML file, moving the mouse towards the top-right of the editor will display icons for several browsers...clicking those will open the current HTML in the respective browser. Not as useful if you're using Django templates, but another piece of IDE-candy nonetheless.

Auto-import is also probably one of my favorite features. It still needs a bit of work, though. This is just a preview release, so I'm sure it'll continuously get better.

Well done, JetBrains!

Answer (score 5):

Something I recently had to figure out was how to pass hardcoded arguments to a Python program when running it. I wanted to do it in the IDE rather than having to switch back and forth to a command window to run the program.

In PyCharm 1.5.2, you can click on `Run`, then `Edit Configurations`. The third textbox from the top, labeled `Script parameters`, allows you to hardcode program parameters. These will be used each time the program is run from PyCharm.