# Can PyCharm follow the link from source editor?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working with project, where previous developer leave many comments with the links on documentation. It's would be very useful, if PyCharm may to follow the links directly from source code. I know that in Visual Studio this feature exist, the links open by CTRL+Click over them. What about PyCharm? I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PyCharm 3.0.2 and Ctrl+Click works for links that starts with `http://`. But for the links that don't start with `http://`(i.e. `www.example.com`), I had to keep the cursor on the link(you don't have to highlight) and the context menu had an option called `Open in Browser` using which you can navigate to that link in the default browser.

Now, when in comments, the Ctrl+Click is not working even for links with `http://`. But the second method(`Open in Browser` from right click context menu on the link) still works so you can still get the job done.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm 3.0.2 Community Edition. Features that you describe not available.

Comment: [According to the PyCharm dev](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562885/1267124), Ctrl+Click pretty much works on anything(that I can verify). 
Is your project a web application though? Because I tested only in Django projects.