# How to surround selected text in PyCharm like with Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext2, pycharm

Is there a way to configure PyCharm to be able to surround selected code with parenthesis by just typing on the parenthesis key, like when we use SublimText 2?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

I think you want something like

`Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys` -> `Surround selection on typing quote or brace`

Comment: On Windows, this is `File | Settings` instead of `Preferences`

Comment: This results in a behavior similar to that in Jupyter Notebook, which makes the switch between the two much smoother. Thanks!

Comment: on mac is `Preferences` instead of `Settings`

Comment: Just to clarify, once this is enabled, go to your code editor window and select part of the text you want wrapped in quotes and then just type `SHIFT` + `'` for example.

Answer (score 20):

PyCharm 4.0 has the option to `Surround With...`, by selecting your code snippet and [pressing](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/ctrl+alt.html)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

or on Mac: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Option 1 should provide you with the functionality you are looking for:

[image: PyCharm Ctrl+Alt+T]

Comment: I tried this, but it also adds a line break.
If I have, say, "print doc", select "doc" and apply this, "doc" turns into "(doc)", as expected, but it goes to another line.

Comment: @DouglasHenrique that behavior should be able to be changed using the $END$ live template variable.

Answer (score 1):

Windows: open pycharm and select file, settings, Editor, Smart Keys, in the list you will check "Surround selection on typing quote or brace", then apply.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJsPF.png)

[Image of pycharm location of smart keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJsPF.png)