# How not to erase selection when trying to put it into brackets Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to find a way to make bracket insertion work the same way in Pycharm as in a jupyter notebook, that is to say, when I have some code selected:

```
some_code
```

and I hit the '(' key, have it put into brackets, like this `(some code)` instead of having my whole selection erased and be left with `()`

Any idea on how to make this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer proposed by Arnoud in '[How to surround selected text in PyCharm like with Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152414/how-to-surround-selected-text-in-pycharm-like-with-sublime-text)' is exactly what you're looking for.

Namely using:

> `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys` -> `Surround selection on
>   typing quote or brace`

The advantage of this method is that it adds brakets without any extra shortcuts to remember.

Answer (score 1):

You may create your own *Live template*:

```
File | Settings...
```

then in the left pane select

```
Editor | Live templates
```

Now click at the green `+` (the topmost icon in the right narrow pane), select `1. Live Template` and write in the `Template text:` exactly this: `($SELECTION$)` - see the following picture.

Then fill in other two fields with something appropriate, e. g.:

[image]

Finally, click in the bottom part on the blue `Define` and from the popup menu check *applicable contexts*, in your case at least *Python*. Accept with OK button.

From now you may select a text, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

[image]

and you may use it (press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the underlined character, i. e. <kbd>P</kbd> in our case):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue in a Jupyter notebook and the solution seems straightforward. Open any notebook, navigate to **settings**, and enable the **Auto Close Brackets** option. You only need to do this once for one notebook, and it will apply to all subsequent notebooks.