# Insert parentheses or quotes after i have typed a text or string

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

consider the following commands:

```
print (help me insert quotes after i have typed)

print "help me insert parentheses after i have typed"
```

i want these to be properly formatted, say

```
print ("help me insert quotes after i have typed")

print ("help me insert parentheses after i have typed")
```

Is there a way to select a text and then enter parentheses without having to cut, enter parentheses and then paste it back?

i use all these: Anaconda, PyCharm, Python

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact answer you are looking for

[How to surround selected text in PyCharm like with Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152414/how-to-surround-selected-text-in-pycharm-like-with-sublime-text)